# Show and hide HTML with angularJS value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to show and hide a `<button>` element in my HTML when a directive value `{{auth?.loggedIn}}` from AngularJS is true or false.

My HTML:

```
<button (click)="onLogin()" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">SSO Login</button>

Currently Logged In?  {{auth?.loggedIn}}

Logged in as:  {{currentUser?.profile?.email}}

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='/secondpage'">Go to second page</button>
```

The idea is when `{{auth?.loggedIn}}` is true, show the second button:
[image]

And when `{{auth?.loggedIn}}` is false, hide the second button:
[image]

Comment: you can use *ngIf on your element

```
*ngIf="expression" 
```
on your end
```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='/secondpage'" *ngIf="auth.loggedIn" >Go to second page</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *ngIf

```
<div *ngIf="auth?.loggedIn">

Currently Logged In?  {{auth?.loggedIn}}

Logged in as:  {{currentUser?.profile?.email}}

</div>
```

Should work for you.

See Angular Documentation: [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the help! My solution was simple using the *ngIf="EXPRESSION":

```
<button (click)="onLogin()" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">SSO Login</button>

Currently Logged In?  {{auth?.loggedIn}}

Logged in as:  {{currentUser?.profile?.email}}

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" *ngIf="auth.loggedIn" onclick="window.location.href='/secondpage'">Go to second page</button>
```